# ORA-32771: Cannot Add File To Bigfile Tablespace

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, oracle-19c

I have 1TB tablespace that have one bigfile , The disk size now full and added extra disk to my server but there is no way to expand Drive that bigfile in it , so need to add another bigfile ,if create new tablespace I got error : ORA-32771: Cannot Add File To Bigfile Tablespace

I have Disk 1 : with 1TB size and one drive named C:
now Added Disk 2 : with 500GB with Latter D:

so I need to expand my database tablespace into two drive or some way that can do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A bigfile tablespace can only contain one datafile, so you cannot expand a bigfile tablespace across two physical disks unless you are using a virtual filesystem or Oracle ASM that makes the added space appear as part of the same disk to the database. Typically this kind of configuration must be planned in advance, before the database is created.

Your only option to use the second physical disk is to create a second, independent tablespace.

> The disk size now full

That said, if your C: drive is 100% full, you may have other problems. Typically, Windows performance starts to deteriorate when the C: drive becomes too full (like over 80%), and your bigfile tablespace is *designed* to fill an entire disk. Placing it on the same drive with your operating system is probably not a good idea. Bigfile tablespaces should generally only be used on disks or filesystems that don't contain any other files.

Comment: Yes , I create webapplication for one years and don't planning for upgrade database . but the company use it to much and added to much devices so the application desigend for smb work under organazation size, I will update and set different database from os drive. That actually can't do anything right?

Comment: It's 100% full and all the app database work perfectly until 100%, Thanks to Oracle (JAVA and ORACLE database Enterprise Edition) and 24GB RAM.

Comment: Good to know , the disk full but all new data if restart server save in memory! (near 16GB will save) in RAM not database!!!! And all system good to go.